# Connection string stored in web.config file doesn't open SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

I am trying to learn to use VS2015 and I have seen a number of similar postings on the internet relating to this problem and none of them have gotten me any closer to a solution.

I am trying to write into a SQL Server database and have tested both my database and connection string and confirm they are both working well.

With that out of the way I went into `web.config` and created a definition for said connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name" 
         connectionString="Data Source=<desktopname>\\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database1"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

As far as I can tell this works fine...

However, when I declare the string as follows:

```
MyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString;
```

Somehow what this returns is not understandable by:

```
SqlConnection iData = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
```

As when I try and "open" the connection it fails... Despite the exact same connection string works when declared like this within the C# code:

```
   SqlConnection iData = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<desktopname>\\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database1");
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

The problem lies with how the information is handled from `web.config` to the string to the `SqlConnection` as far as I can tell.

Notably everything runs perfectly unless I use the string as the connection string...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your database server? Is a SQLExpress or SQLServer?

Comment: what is the error you get when you use variable in SqlConnection constructor?

also i see that the variable you've defined and the one you are using are not the same. i hope that is just a typo in your question and not in your code.

Comment: You get any exception/error? Please paste here...

Comment: Can you log into db using this credentials by Management Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# the backslash needs to be doubled, because the compiler treats the backslash as an escape character. And then the `\\` compiles to `\` in the actual string used at runtime.

In XML that is not the case, it uses a different parser, so in Web.Config you should use a single `\`:

```
<add name="Name" connectionString="Data Source=<desktopname>\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database1"/>
```

On top of that you may also need to add `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`:

```
<add
    name="Name"
    connectionString="Data Source=<desktopname>\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database1"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

*Reference:* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does '/' not escape the "/" symbol in XML?

Comment: XML treats both '/' and '\' as they are. It needs escaping for other characters, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1220550 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add : providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in your "< add name"

```
<add name ="Name" connectionString="Data Source=<desktopname>\\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database1"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```